# Disable scroll up and down when open left menu

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

When I open left menu, there has table view which have users profile on the right of the screen. I want to disable scrolling up and down, when I open left menu. Is that possible ? Is it the only solution disabled scrolling on users profile screen ?

Comment: Sorry but Question not clear.

Comment: do you want to stop the tableView from scrolling?

Comment: I have an table view screen. There are many user profiles. Also my app has left menu which have lots of button. When I opened left menu, you can see table view right on the screen. While open left menu, you can scrool on table view. I want to disable scrool while open left menu. Now, Is that clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you are using autoLayout this solution do the job:

```
tableView.alwaysBounceVertical = NO.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the UITableView interaction by calling

```
self.tableView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

When you open the menu

Or if you want to keep the functionality but only disable the scrolling, just implement the UIScrollViewDelegate methods (UITableView is a subclass of UIScrollView) and in didScroll method add

```
[tableView setContentOffset:tableView.contentOffset animated:NO];
```